# PHP and mysql checkbox insert

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am working on a project where i need to  pass values (from a list of products) of multiple checkboxes AND text boxes to a table (new_orders) on the database.

I managed to create the list retrieving the products from the table articles, but i can't insert the products that i choose with  the quantities that i insert to the table new_orders on the database.

Here is the code:

```
foreach($A_result as $key => $value) // για χρηση όλων των αντικειμένων του πίνακα A_apotelesma
{


// shows al the products
    echo "<tr> 
              <td align=center>".$j++."</td>
              <td align=center>".$value['name']."</td>
              <td align=center>".$value['price']."</td> ";

echo"<td> // each product has a checkbox and a text box to enter the quantity

            <input type=checkbox name=\"article[]\"></input>
            <input type=text name='quantity_".$value['id_article']."' size='3' maxlength='2'>
         </td>";

    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name='id_article' value=".$value['id_article']."></td>"; 
    echo"<td><input type='hidden' name=\"code_user\" value=\"code_user\"></td>"; 

    echo"</tr>";
}
}

?>  

 // The form above redirects to the insert_order.php page:


<?php

include("conn.php");

session_start();

$checkbx=$_POST['article'];

if($_POST['article']){

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($checkbx);$i++){

$quantity=$_POST['quantity_.$id_article'];

$username=$_SESSION['logged_user_username'];

$insert_order_query= "INSERT INTO new_orders (id_article, quantity, username) VALUES (".$id_article.",".$quantity.", '".$username."')";
//echo $insert_order_query;
$insert_order=mysql_query($insert_order_query) or die('Error,query failed!!'); 
 if ($insert_order)
     echo '<script language="javascript">alert("New order created!"); document.location="logged_in_user.php?menu=1";</script>';
 else
 {
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("The order has not been created.")</script>';
    echo '<script language="javascript"> document.location="logged_in_user.php?menu=1.php"; </script>';
    exit();
 }
}
}

?>
```

I ALWAYS get the error message.

Comment: tl;dr but I think it would help if you tell other users what the error message is

Comment: Obligatory use prepared statements and not `mysql` because it is depreciated and you are vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: Also in this statement `$quantity=$_POST['quantity_.$id_article'];` What are you trying to accomplish? should it be `$quantity=$_POST['quantity_'. $id_article];`

Comment: the error message is the or die message "Error, query failed!!"

Comment: with the statement $quantity=$_POST['quantity_'. $id_article]; i want to retrieve the article number to which corresponds the quantity entered on the previous form (with the checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

Single qoutes are missing in

```
$insert_order_query= "INSERT INTO new_orders (id_article, quantity, username) VALUES (".$id_article.",".$quantity.", '".$username."')";
```

try something like

```
$insert_order_query= "INSERT INTO new_orders (id_article, quantity, username) VALUES ('".$id_article."','".$quantity."', '".$username."')";
```

but echo that $insert_order_query

paste here what you get - debugging tells a lot:)

EDIT

and especially do echo your $quantity

Comment: I used single quotes but no luck :-( Thanks for the debugging hint!

Comment: did u echo $insert_order_query sometimes query fails too if values are not comin in mentioned fields echo $insert_order_query can show you that too

Answer (score 0):

that is because 
    `$quantity=$_POST['quantity_.$id_article'];`
should be 
    `$quantity=$_POST['quantity_'.$id_article];`